# Query specific data from sqlite database with php

Tags: php, sqlite

Hi there i am using a sqlite database to manage reservations on a system (written in php and html) that I built. I have managed to connect to the database and run a simple count query that runs (see code below). However i am finding it difficult to execute a query that will allow me to select reservations between two dates i.e (2018-02-20 and 2018-02-25). I have also enclosed a screenshot of my database for visualization purposes.

Code for count query:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:daypilot.sqlite');

$query = 'SELECT count(*) FROM events;';

$result = $db->query($query);

$data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "There are {$data['count(*)']} bookings made\n";
?>
```

Comment: Looks like your screenshot didn't make it.

Comment: Well, you didn't try: `SELECT count(*) FROM events WHERE some_date BETWEEN '2018-02-20' AND '2018-02-25'`

Comment: 1 Tom T  2018-02-23T07:00:00 2018-02-23T08:00:00 1

Comment: That is an example row of data and the fields are as follows...id, name, start, end , resource_id

Comment: Help would be greatly appreciated on this as its the last step in this particular project

Comment: Also forgot to say that i would like to put the results of the query in some sort of html view in the browser

Comment: hi how can i open a database created with System.data.sqlite and has password with php and sqlite3 ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll be passing input to your query, you'll want to use a prepared statement rather than just `query()`. It looks like your events table has two dates, so the following query should catch all events that overlap a specified date range.

```
$start = '2018-02-20';
$end = '2018-02-25';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE `end` > ? AND `start` < ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$start, $end]);
$events = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($events as $event) {
    var_dump($event);  // output with your desired formatting here
}
```

Comment: Thank you this query has executed without any error. Would you recommend a table of some sort to display the results ?

Comment: It really just depends on how you want it to look and what you want to do with it. An HTML table is usually appropriate to display rows from a database, but it's just as valid to have a stack of divs. A table can be advantageous if you're displaying quite a bit of data, because you can use something like https://datatables.net/ to easily make it sortable/filterable/etc.

Comment: can you recommend a table format as this is what i require and im very confused but what to do in this area !!

Comment: How might i implement the datatables.net the format looks very slick

Comment: Here's a basic example of how to output a table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465046/output-a-php-multi-dimensional-array-to-a-html-table/2465168#2465168

Comment: The datatables documentation has some examples of how to apply it to a table once you have one. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: This is my code but this error is showing and i cant spot where the error is. very sorry for pestering but this is working so thank you. 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<',

Comment: <table>
<tr>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>contact</th>
  <th>start</th>
  <th>end</th>
  <th>resouce_id</th>


</tr>
<?php foreach ($_POST['events'] as $event): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $event['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['contact'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['start'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['end'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['resource_id'] ?></td>

  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
?>

Comment: That looks okay for the most part. Just be sure you close your PHP tag (with `?>`) before you use it since it's outputting raw HTML at first. That's probably what's causing the error. Also, you'll just want `$events`, not `$_POST['events']`.

Comment: a syntax error is still here with this code am i missing a closing tag that i cant see  <table>
<tr>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>contact</th>
  <th>start</th>
  <th>end</th>
  <th>resouce_id</th>


</tr>
<?php foreach $events as $event): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $event['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['contact'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['start'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['end'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event['resource_id'] ?></td>

  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>